# NDBI- Normalized Difference builtup Index showing high values in snow and ice covered area

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-api

[image]I derived NDBI using google earth engine but on to visualization the high values of ndbi also representing the snow covered and ice area. Which methodology should i use to get buit up areas only?

here the code, i used Sentinel-2 MSI: MultiSpectral Instrument, Level-2A dataset

```
var kullu = admin2.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM2_NAME','Kullu'));var filtered = s2.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 10)).filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-01-01','2022-01-01')) .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(kullu)).filter(ee.Filter.eq('SPACECRAFT_NAME','Sentinel-2A')); print(filtered.size());
var ndbi = image.normalizedDifference(['B11','B8']).rename(['ndbi']);
var ndbivis = { min: 0, max:1, palette: ['white', 'red']};
Map.addLayer(ndbi.clip(kullu),ndbivis, 'NDBI');
```

Answer (score 0):

The paper on NDBI uses a very non-snowy area:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/248977308_Use_of_normalized_difference_built-up_index_in_automatically_mapping_urban_areas_from_TM_imagery

and so its possible the NDBI reads high for snow.

But perhaps if you also compute the *NDSI* (normalised difference *snow* index https://www.usgs.gov/landsat-missions/normalized-difference-snow-index) you can use high values of that to crop out snow from your building index. But maybe that reads high for buildings too?

Comment: yeah that's the point. Also, that why I was asking the alternative methodology to get built up areas.

Comment: Yes, and that's why I answered. What have you researched and tried already?